# How can I cast an uint8[] dynamic array to uint[]?

Tags: solidity, go-ethereum, contract-development, contract-design

How can I convert my uint8[] to uint[] in Solidity? I have a function that expects uint[], but my array has type uint8[].

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since you cannot only implicitly or explicitly convert from uint8[] to uint256[], you would have to do something like this:

```
contract array {


function conversion (uint8[] array8) returns(uint[] array256) {
   for (uint i = 0 ; i < array8.length ; i++ ) {
       array256[i] = array8[i];

   }

   return array256;
}

}
```

Answer (score 2):

Maybe something like this?

```
contract X {
    uint8[] public arr8 = [3,4,5];
    uint256[] public arr256;

    function myFunc(uint[] _arr256) public {
        arr256 = _arr256;
    }

    function proxyFunc(uint8[] _arr8) public {
        uint[] memory _arr256 = new uint[](_arr8.length);
        for (uint i = 0; i < _arr8.length; i++) {
            _arr256[i] = uint256(_arr8[i]);
        }
        myFunc(_arr256);
    }
}
```